# Libraries for Choosing Color?

Tags: colors

Do any open source libraries exist for programatically selecting and rating the compatibility of sets of colors using [color theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_scheme)?

It would be very useful to be able to select color palettes based on simple color harmony rules like complimentary, analogous, triadic, and tetradic colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this: [Harmonies theory and math](http://easyrgb.com/index.php?X=WEEL).

Also of interest is the rest of the [EasyRGB](http://easyrgb.com/) site, which will explain how to do RGB to HSV, etc.

While it's not source code, it's the formulas for calculating the values.

Also interesting: ["Color Jack"](http://www.colorjack.com/sphere/)

Comment: It looks like the EasyRGB was the ticket: http://easyrgb.com/index.php?X=WEEL

It looks like it's a lot easier than I thought. They're just degree offsets on the color wheel.

Comment: Yer ... but you have to get to the wheel from RGB (if you're doing what I'm doing)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer and it's not open source, but you might take a look at what they are doing at [Adobe's Kuler web site.](http://kuler.adobe.com/) They have [API Documentation](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/kulerdev/home) that might be worth a read.

Comment: +1, awesome site for designers.

Comment: (virtual -1) because we want to see how it's done, not because we want it done =)